# AngularJS gives 404 (Not Found) on views after setting html5Mode on true

Tags: angularjs

I have a small AngularJS website where I use one controller and a view. I wanted to remove the /# in the URL with `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`, but here starts the problem.

My code:

```
[...]

    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            $routeProvider
            .when('/', 
            {
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html', 
                controller: 'HomeController'
            })
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
        }]);
```

When I do this I get the error that he can't find the home view on views/home.html (which is the correct path). When I delete the html5mode for removing the /# in the URL it all works just fine. 
With this:

```
[...]
    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $routeProvider
        .when('/Project', 
        {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html', 
            controller: 'HomeController'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/Project'});
    }]);
```

Summary: when I add the html5mode it gives me the error that he can't find the view. When I remove it it all works.

Anyone who has an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Check your browser's *Net* tab to see what URL it's trying to load for the view template file. Chances are, it'll be `/Project/views/home.html`. You generally need server URL rewriting to use HTML5 mode

Comment: The general consensus is to also add a `<base>` tag for resolving relative links

Comment: It loaded `/views/home.html`. I changed `templateUrl: 'views/home.html'` to `templateUrl: '/Project/views/home.html'` and now it works. Is this a good solution? ^^